# What's the purpose of modal verb "would" before "seen"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Kat: Worst thing Andrei ever did to me was that offer he made me. Let
> me go if I agreed never to see my son again. I shouted and... swore.
> But **he'd** seen it on my face, just for an instant. I considered it.

What's the purpose of modal verb "would" before "seen" ?

Source: Christopher Nolan's movie [*Tenet* (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenet_(film))

Comment: But it is HAD not WOULD. He HAD seen it.

Comment: I can see how this is confusing. Both "he had" and "he would" contract to "he'd." In this case, "he had" is intended.

Comment: Yes, _he'd seen it_ means _he had seen it_. With _would_, the phrase would be _he would have seen it_. I am not sure _he would have seen it_ would be shorted as _he'd seen it_. As I remember _would_ isn't shorted as _'d_, in that case.

Comment: @apaderno *he would have seen it* could become *he'd have seen it* - sometimes pronounced as *he'd've seen it*, but very rarely written that way. However, you are right: *he would have seen it* can't become *he'd seen it*, because the word *have* can't just vanish.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on an erroneous assumption about a text. (Had OP made the correct assumption, he presumably wouldn't have had any question at all.) There is little for others to gain from this question, since they will likely interpret the original text correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> He had seen it on my face.

> He had noticed it on my face.

to stress the fact he HAD seen (the past perfect) the doubt (I assume) on her face.

Comment: In particular, the "seeing" likely happened in a brief moment before the "shouting and swearing," so "had seen" reflects that ordering.